# MapReduce - How to get many map tasks than the worker nodes with small input file

Tags: hadoop, 3d, mapreduce

I want to generate Digital Elevation Models  data for a very large area. At least 18 x 10^12 samples. To generate those data I need only starting location, size of domain and resolution.

For example

input :

```
ORIGIN_LAT=33.663901;ORIGIN_LON=-117.894687;ORIGIN_DEPTH =0.000000
SIZE_DOMAIN_LAT=4000.000000;SIZE_DOMAIN_LON=4000.000000;SIZE_DOMAIN_DEPTH =1600.000000
```

output :

```
-117.894687,  33.663901, 0.000000  

-117.894687 ,    33.663901 ,     -200.000000 

-117.894687     , 33.663901 ,    -300.000000 

-117.894687 ,    33.663901  , -400.000000 

-117.894687     , 33.663901 ,    -500.000000 

-117.894687 ,    33.663901 ,     -600.000000 

-117.894687     , 33.663901     , -700.000000 

-117.894687 ,    33.663901  , -800.000000 

-117.894687     , 33.663901     , -900.000000 

-117.894687 ,    33.663901 ,     -1000.000000

.....................
```

So I am wondering how to get more map tasks than the worker nodes. Becuase input is very small file .

I am not sure I misunderstood the concepts but if the program is running in one node there is no use of using cluster and here only the map phase generating data, I am using zero reducer.

Actually I am analysing these data with another MR program presently generating data with external program and its not efficient. So I need to generate these  data with MR program.

I have 5 nodes in Cluster and The size of input file is very small to generate at least 5 map tasks. How to use MR parallelism to generate these data ?

1 Solution

I divided large region into several subregion in map() and assign those to reducer.

Comment: So I'm not clear on this. Is the problem you're trying to address that you have many small input files and that is slowing Hadoop down?

Comment: my input file is very small. but i need to generate large data from that 1 input file .                                                   but number of map tasks depend on size of input file?

Comment: for generating 2x 10^7 samples took 8 hours in Macbook with 8GB ram and nearly 2 days with low performance laptop. So i want use parallelism in MR to generate those samples in less time .

Comment: are these input files already in HDFS file system ?

Comment: So really you don't want the input file to actually be the mapper key. You want it to be an id for what section of the output the current mapper will generate and each mapper to access the same input file?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a petty solution, but it might work:

- You may repeat the same input file or have single line input in each file with different values!
- And if you want add a counter value at start and in order to detect that in the mapper and process accordingly
- Make the file to be a gzipped one, this will force hadoop to have as many mappers as the number of files.

For the last point above, you will need to add the following property to core-site.xml file:

```
<property>
    <name>io.compression.codecs</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec</value>
  </property>
```

And following property to mapred-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.output.compression.codec</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the parameter `mapred.reduce.tasks` requests Hadoop framework to create number of map tasks, it's not guaranteed operation. Hence, the number of map tasks are governed by the number of input splits which depends on the generic formula. Here is the link on how the job client computes input splits for textual file

[How job client in hadoop compute inputSplits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078547/how-job-client-in-hadoop-compute-inputsplits/16086404#16086404)

With the above explanation, if more number of map tasks needs to be created for small input file. You may have to follow either of these approaches.

1. Split your input files into 5 small input files so that at least 5 map tasks are created for your 5 node cluster or
2. Adjust the parameters such as `mapred.min.split.size` and `dfs.block.size` so that more number of map tasks are created for your input file.